# Problems installing PythonTidy with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, tidy

i'm a new to mac user and i'm having trouble installing python tidy for sublime text 2
(see below). Can someone help me interpret this error?

User:Python_files user$ sudo pip install http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidy-1.22.python

Downloading/unpacking http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidy-1.22.python

Downloading PythonTidy-1.22.python (147kB): 147kB downloaded

Cannot unpack file /private/tmp/pip-iUmMcZ-unpack/PythonTidy-1.22.python (downloaded from /tmp/pip-H2TIvP-build, content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format

Cleaning up...

Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-H2TIvP-build
Storing debug log for failure in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that gets downloaded from http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidy-1.22.python when you use pip is a text file containing python source and not an archive file. You don't need pip to install PythonTidy. If you just copy all the text from that web page and paste in a file with extension .py, you should be good to go. You will have to add the path where you keep this file to your $PATH so that sublime text 2 is able to find it.

Comment: Hello and thank you.  I ended up installing the package using git as explained by this site   https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PythonTidy   , and now I see it in my packages in sublime as a folder "SublimePythonTidy".    However, when I try to use it, (control + alt(option)+command+t) nothing happens.  any idea why? sorry, i'm new to mac and sublime